# How to setup git with codecommit so i don't have to add ssh key id everytime?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, aws-codecommit

i have my ssh uploaded to aws and i can do (i'm using ubuntu):

```
git clone ssh://my-ssh-key-id@git-codecommit.xxx.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/yyy
```

however i wan't to be able just copy-paste the repo url provided by codeCommit and simply use it without key-id, like:

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.xxx.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/yyy
```

how should i configure my git or ssh to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should suffice to add the following to your `.ssh/config`.

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
   User my-ssh-key-id
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify your ~/.ssh/config file to have something like this:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
    User APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
```

Where 'User' is your SSH Key ID generated for your IAM user (in the IAM console), and 'IdentityFile' is the location of the RSA private key file you generated using 'ssh-keygen', which is associated with your IAM user.

Source: [CodeCommit SSH setup documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html)